# Do we ever see Spider-Man's healing power in action?

Tags: spider-man, marvel

Spider-Man is listed as having accelerated [healing powers](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_Factor). I never knew he could heal faster than an average human.

Do we ever see an clear examples of this in canon, his skin knitting back before or eyes for example?

Comment: he could heal faster than an average human, but not as fast as wolverine, that would cause his skin knitting back. Others include, quicksilver also who have an accelerated healing power.

Comment: http://static8.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/7/72524/3421805-2655467372-spide.jpg

Comment: http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/7/72524/3421806-1047255117-spide.jpg

Comment: [Before](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11111/111119621/3785069-d550487bd6bd966b7ea1351f38e74277.png) & [24 hours later](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11111/111119621/3785077-826b1c9dd26702d2c4c69f54e15415f6.png)

Comment: @Richard 4 clearly answer-worthy images.

Comment: @kallisar - I'd post them except for the fact that I'm a) mobile at the moment b) Have no idea which comics these panels are from and c) found these with next to no effort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Until Wolverine's debut in the Marvel Universe (in 1974), Spider-Man was the go-to hero in the Marvel Universe for fast-healing action. (While the Hulk's power has been dubbed regeneration, it the past, he appeared to be more invulnerable than regenerative.) However, unlike Wolverine or Deadpool or any of the current crop of superhealing heroes, Spider-Man's abilities were far more subdued.

- One of the first things to remember about Spider-Man is his extreme durability. Despite his very human appearance, he is capable of taking blows from opponents which would kill normal humans, easily. He has faced off against the Lizard, the Sandman, the Wrecker, Doctor Octopus, Morlun and even the herald of Galactus, Firelord!
- It was common practice for him to take a brutal beating at the hands of his enemies who often had superhuman strength greater than his own and be back in action in less than a day.
- He has fought against a variety of enemies whose physical powers dwarf his own. Thus if and when he gets hit, it is partially his athletic abilities to roll with the punch and his superhuman durability to suck up that damage. Possible one of the greatest beatdowns Spider-Man ever recovered from was facing his vampiric enemy Morlun.

[image]

- After such beatdowns, he depends on his superhuman vitality to pick up the slack. He could heal from injuries which should take weeks for normal humans in hours.
- Bullet wounds heal in about eight hours unless they hit something really important (like his heart). He can literally sleep them off, if they pass directly through his body. This was relatively early in his career.

[image]

- If bullets remain lodged in his body, he may need medical attention but his vitality is such he could survive, get treated and still be on his feet and fighting in three days. Not Wolverine-level, most certainly, but I wouldn't suggest Joe-SixPack try that. I wouldn't recommend an MMA fighter try it for that matter. That is a level of healing far greater than the human norm.

[image]

- He has also shown considerable resistance to diseases which affect normal Humans. He may catch a flu, get debilitated or even end up with pnuemonia (usually through not taking are of himself or over-extending himself) but once he stops moving and rests, his superhuman constitution directs all of his considerable ability toward correcting the problem. There are clips of him recovering from a devastating bout of influenza, overnight.

[image]

[image]

- He has recovered from second and third degree burns over half his body in less than two days after they were treated medically. Spider-Man's superhuman vitality is far more subtle than the flashier healing powers of Wolverine and Family or Deadpool.
- All things considered, with Spider-Man's rogues gallery, each capable of dishing out a world of pain if they can lay a glove on him, his enhanced healing abilities are a godsend. He's like an old-school Timex: takes a licking and keeps on ticking.

[image]

Comment: Which comics do these panels come from?

Answer (score 3):

He once had acid splashed onto his face. He healed it in a few hours without medical attention. You can see this in *Amazing Spider-Man 594*:

[image: Amazing Spider-Man 594, Spider-Man heals acid splashed in his face]

A SHIELD medical doctor took one look at his body and stated his body showed signs of sustaining life-threatening injuries that should have killed him without a healing factor of some sorts. This occurs in *Spider-Man Unlimited v3*:

[image: Spider-Man Unlimited v3,]

He also healed a broken arm in 24 hours. Which would take a real-life person several months along with physical therapy. This is shown in *Amazing Spider-Man 199*:

[image: Amazing Spider-Man 199]

It's not crazy like Wolverine but as long as Spider-Man isn't outright dead and can get back home. He can be expected to make a full recovery by sleeping it off.